# setup function returns undefined when testing a custom hook usePrevious

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have got code for usePrevious hook from somewhere on internet. The code for usePrevious looks like:

```js
export const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
};
```

Now, I am learing testing react with jest and enzyme. So, I tried to test usePrevious and got some problems. Here is my test case:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'enzyme';

import { usePrevious } from './customHooks';

const Component = ({ children, value }) => children(usePrevious(value));
const setup = (value) => {
  let returnVal = '';
  render(
    <Component value={value}>
      {
        (val) => {
          returnVal = val;
          return null;
        }
      }
    </Component>,
  );
  return returnVal;
};

describe('usePrevious', () => {
  it('returns something', () => {
    const test1 = setup('test');
    const test2 = setup(test1);
    expect(test2).toBe('test');
  });
});
```

When the test execution completes, I get this error:

```
Expected: 'test', Received: undefined
```

Can anyone please let me know why am I getting undefined and is this the correct way to test custom hoooks in react?

**After suggestion from comments from @Dmitrii G, I have changed my code to re-render the component (Previously I was re-mounting the component).**

Here is the updated code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { usePrevious } from './customHooks';

const Component = ({ value }) => {
  const hookResult = usePrevious(value);
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{hookResult}</span>
      <span>{value}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

Component.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

Component.defaultProps = {
  value: '',
};


describe('usePrevious', () => {
  it('returns something', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component value="test" />);
    console.log('>>>>> first time', wrapper.find('div').childAt(1).text());
    expect(wrapper.find('div').childAt(0).text()).toBe('');

    // Test second render and effect
    wrapper.setProps({ value: 'test2' });
    console.log('>>>>> second time', wrapper.find('div').childAt(1).text());
    expect(wrapper.find('div').childAt(0).text()).toBe('test');
  });
});
```

But still I am getting the same error

```
Expected: "test", Received: ""
```

**Tests Passes when settimeout is introduced:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { usePrevious } from './customHooks';

const Component = ({ value }) => {
  const hookResult = usePrevious(value);
  return <span>{hookResult}</span>;
};

Component.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

Component.defaultProps = {
  value: '',
};


describe('usePrevious', () => {
  it('returns empty string when component is rendered first time', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component value="test" />);
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find('span').text()).toBe('');
    }, 0);
  });
  it('returns previous value when component is re-rendered', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component value="test" />);
    wrapper.setProps({ value: 'test2' });
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find('span').text()).toBe('test');
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

I am not a big fan of using settimeout, so I feel that probably i am doing some mistake. If anyone knows a solution that does not use settimeout, feel free to post here. Thank you.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @DmitriiG. I expect my test to return 'test', but it is returning undefined

Comment: your usePrevious always returns the 'previous' value which in your cause is initial undefined. Your code works as intended.

Comment: @DmitriiG.I am calling setup function twice, so I expect the value `test` instead of `undefined`

Comment: @DmitriiG.Can you please let me know the correct way of testing this?

Comment: check here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html the how to test components with hooks part

Comment: okay, i will check that and try to fix the problem. Thank you.

Comment: the reason yours didnt work is that you create two different Components with two different usePrevious refs. in the link I shared they show how to create a single component and make it rerender which will fill your usePrevious with a value

Comment: @DmitriiG.I have read that and can find that they are using state. They are simulating click of the button which will change the state and due to that their component will rerender. Should I do that same thing to test my hook? I don't know if it is a good practice to do so to test a custom hook? I must admit here that I am really new to testing.

Comment: @DmitriiG.I have tried to rerender the component instead of mounting it again. Still getting the same results. Please take a look at the update part in question.

Comment: @DmitriiG.I have posted a solution in the question. But that is using settimeout. Can you please help me improve the test?

Comment: try using `mount()`. Shallow renderer has known issues with ruining `useEffect`, I'm surprised it works with timeout as workaround

Comment: @skyboyer I will try to do that and will let you know the results. Thanks

Comment: @skyboyer Yes, when using `mount()` instead of  `shallow()`, I don't need settimeout. Thank you for help. Please post it as an answer, so that I can close the question and someone in future stumbling upon this may find a solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enzyme by the hood utilizes React's shallow renderer. And it has [issue with running effects](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17321). Not sure if it's going to be fixed soon.
Workaround with `setTimeout` was a surprise to me, did not know it works. Unfortunately, it is not universal approach since you'd need to use that on any change that cases re-render. Really fragile.

As a solution you can use `mount()` instead.

Also you may mimic shallow rendering with `mount()` with mocking every nested component:

```
jest.mock("../MySomeComponent.jsx", () =>
  (props) => <span {...props}></span>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it as an answer, I think this may help someone in future.